# mysqli_fetch_array structure error

Tags: php, mysqli

can you help me figure out the correct structure for this mysqli_fetch_array? I read up on http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp but I still don't know what am I missing.

I am still new to php!

I am getting this error.

Notice: Undefined variable: video_name in D:\xampp\htdocs\video_upload\index.php on line 68

```
<div id="box">
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT 'id', 'name', 'url' FROM videos");
while($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $video_id = $run['id'];
    $video_name = $run['name'];
    $video_url = $run['url'];

}
?>

<a href='vide.php?videos=<?php echo $video_url; ?>'>
<div id='url'>
<?php echo $video_name; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Please check [`w3fools.com`](http://www.w3fools.com) and get to know why you shouldn't use `w3schools.com`.

Comment: What is your problem here..?? mention it.

Comment: Aaaaand what appears to be the problem...?

Comment: Posted the error in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'` instead of `. Change that first. Then put the anchor tag inside the loop.

Edit like this,

```
<div id="box">
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `id`, `name`, `url` FROM videos");
while($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $video_id = $run['id'];
    $video_name = $run['name'];
    $video_url = $run['url'];
    ?>
        <a href='vide.php?videos=<?php echo $video_url; ?>'>
        <div id='url'>
             <?php echo $video_name; ?>    
        </div>
        </a>
   <?php
}
?>
</div>
```